# Why was I banned from flagging?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, flag-ban

> [image]

On my newest flag page there is only one declined flag - for 19 oct. And suddenly... banned. Investigation?

Screenshot of newest flags:

[image]

Comment: Surely it wasn't just one flag... the rules are at least 25% declined and at least 10 total in a window of time. Can you provide a screenshot of your flag history?

Comment: @jan the page or stats?

Comment: Eek. The image is too big and I can't zoom out. Can you make it smaller so that the text is actually unreadable?

Comment: @jan what do you mean... it is already very small... in address bar you can add any valid prefix you want to resize the image.

Comment: I've edited to link to the bigger image version.

Comment: It's important to note that not all flags are equal.  Some are low-rep versions of close votes, others are applied to comments.  I think it's possible that if you have a really bad history of flagging answers, then you could get the ban, even if your comment flags are ok.

Comment: The flag ban applies to when flags are handled, not when they are flagged.  So if you had a backlog of older flags in which a number were declined within the last 10 days, that would trigger the ban

Answer (score -8):

In short, it's because your flags are statistically worse, a lot worse, than flags left by the average SO user.  So the system would rather wait for that average user to come along and make a decision on a post than bother moderators and review queues with your assessment.

If you want to know what is bad about your flags, you'll have to discuss them individually.  We can't get anything useful from mere screenshots of the flag list, without context.

Note that this doesn't mean that the value of your flags is negative... but it does mean the value is less than the opportunity cost.  The moderators have thousands of flags waiting to be dealt with, so they want to see only flags that can be trusted.

In addition to statistical analysis, sometimes a moderator will manually apply a short-term flag or review ban to someone who left a flag or review that is clearly against the official community-accepted policy, indicating that either you haven't read the policy (and therefore shouldn't be flagging/reviewing), or are thinking you know better than the policy, in which case your flags aren't welcome.  Mostly these short-term bans are to get your attention and make you re-read the policy.

Comment: We can't manually apply flag bans (yet).